# DataTemplateSelector.SelectTemplate not getting called for root items of `TreeView`

Tags: c#, wpf

I got a `TreeView`:

```
<TreeView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" ItemsSource="{Binding ResourceInstanceRootItems}" SelectedItemChanged="TreeView_SelectedItemChanged_2">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplateSelector>
                <local:ResourceInstDataTemplateSelector/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplateSelector>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
 </TreeView>
```

and the DataTemplateSelector:

```
public class ResourceInstDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate
        SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        FrameworkElement element = container as FrameworkElement;

        if (element != null && item != null && item is ResourceInstance)
        {
            ResourceInstance ri = item as ResourceInstance;
            DataTemplate temp = null;
            if (ri.Parent == null)
                temp = App.Current.Resources["parent_item"] as DataTemplate;
            else if (ri.DependingInstance == null)
                temp = App.Current.Resources["simple_instance"] as DataTemplate;
            else
                temp = App.Current.Resources["dependent_instance"] as DataTemplate;

            return temp;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

The problem is, `ResourceInstDataTemplateSelector.SelectTemplate` does not get called for root items in the `TreeView` and they show as only empty arrows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should be setting the selector on the TreeView directly, not putting an ItemTemplate on the TreeView which has the selector on it, e.g.

```
<TreeView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" ItemsSource="{Binding ResourceInstanceRootItems}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplateSelector>
        <local:ResourceInstDataTemplateSelector/>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplateSelector>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: Thanks. I am shamed I missed that.